# How to validate the controls which are in accordion? Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net

How to validate controls using java script in accordion control in asp.net. When i am trying to validate control it is throwing error.

```
function myfun() 
    {
        alert(document.getElementById("txt").value);                         
    }
```

The control txt which is in accordion control. please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use clientid

```
function myfun() 
{
    alert(document.getElementById('<%=txt.ClientID%>').value);                         
}
```